# Why do I have to use the Object class as a reference type to make this program work?

Tags: java, object

The following class is the **correct** way. The code with 4 stars around it is what is going to change in the next (incorrect) class.

```
public class Hello
{
    public void go()
    {
        Hello aDog = new Hello();
        **Object** sameDog = getObject(aDog);
        System.out.println(aDog);
        System.out.println(sameDog);
    }

    public Object getObject(Object o)
    {
        return o;
    }
}
```

---

This is the next class

```
public class Hello
{
    public void go()
    {
        Hello aDog = new Hello();
        **Hello** sameDog = getObject(aDog);
        System.out.println(aDog);
        System.out.println(sameDog);
    }

    public Object getObject(Object o)
    {
        return o;
    }
}
```

And finally, I have my tester class.

```
public class HelloTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello a = new Hello();
        a.go();
    }
}
```

The following output is from the **correct** class:

```
Hello@2a139a55
Hello@2a139a55
```

The **incorrect** code does not work (obviously).

Why is this?

Comment: Because your method returns an `Object`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth But doesn't the Hello class inherit everything from Object?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean you can do `Object a = new Object(); Hello b = a;`.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getObject` is explicitly declared to return `java.lang.Object` - that's why it the compiler will not allow you to assign its result to a variable of a more explicit type, which is in this case `Dog`. There is nothing declaring that the return type of this method will be of the same type like the parameter - it could be any `Object` can be passed and therefore the return type is `Object`.

If you rewrite your code to use generics, you can be sure to get a `Dog` instance at compile time:

```
public <T> T getObject(T object)
{
    return object;
}
```

This declaration consists of multiple parts:

- `public` - the method is public.
- `<T>` all parameters of this method are declared here. In this case this is a unconstrained (e.g. no upper or lower bounds like `T extends List`) single parameter - `T`.
- `T` - the return type of this method will be the generic type `T`.
- `getObject` - the method name.
- `T object` - a parameter of type `T` named object.

Answer (score 0):

The function getObject() returns an "Object" type object.
When pointing to an Object type with a Hello type pointer,you are doing implicit up casting, which is not allowed

Comment: Upcasting is allowed.  It's downcasting that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

getObject returns an Object whereas you assigned it to a Hello type.
You should "cast" it to an Hello object:

```
        **Hello** sameDog = (Hello) getObject(aDog);
```